# TeamViewer not working on MacOS Mojave via ssh

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, teamviewer, macos-mojave

I need TeamViewer on my Mac to work remotely. I installed it via ssh using the command line

```
brew cask install teamviewer
```

which worked fine.

However, I seem to be unable to configure TeamViwer from the command line. Due to Corona, I cannot personally access the Mac at the moment, which means I have to do everything via ssh.

I tried

```
$ /Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/TeamViewer
```

which fails with

> _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL. 
>   Could not find domain for 
>   Could not find domain for 
>   2020-03-23 18:53:18.935 TeamViewer[1695:9920] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'ClientCallsAuxiliary': Connection interrupted

and then stops until I exit with Ctrl+C.

I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324797/1574054), which gave me

```
$ open /Applications/TeamViewer.app
```

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Applications/TeamViewer.app.

and

```
$ sudo open /Applications/TeamViewer.app
```

> LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/TeamViewer.app.

Furthermore, the path `Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.*` does not exist.

What do I have to do next? What else can I try?